Placing Pictures into Cells
I am currently working on an Excel inventory list for my model railway.
My problem is that almost after every automation error (error 440) my Excel crashes (Microsoft Surface Book 1TB 16 Gb i7).
In the code in my post, the goal is to insert a picture of one of the municipal or cantonal coats of arms into the line of the locomotive and it somehow worked when I tried it out, but suddenly there is always an error and it crashes.
Can anyone help me?
'Einbettung des Wappens
'Auswählen der Zeile
Range("H" & last1).Select
'Einfügen des Bildes
WithWorksheets("Liste").Pictures.Insert("C:\Users\Sven\OneDrive\Desktop\Modellbahn\Modellbahn Inventar" & "\" & Lok_Wappen_Auswahl.Value & ".jpg")
    .Height = 18
    .Name = "WappenBild"
    
End With

With Worksheets("Liste").Shapes("WappenBild")
    .Top = Worksheets("Liste").Range("H" & last1).Top
    .Left = Worksheets("Liste").Range("H" & last1).Left
    .Placement = 1
    
End With
Worksheets("Liste").Shapes("WappenBild").Select
Worksheets("Liste").Shapes("WappenBild").PlacePictureInCell

I have tried to switch between "Shapes" and "Pictures" and some things work despite error messages
